# String.Format for Phonenumber leading with zeros

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I just want to ask about how can i add padding on `string.Format` so that when I show it , the mask is applied with leading zeros

Heres my c# code

```
Model.Phone = String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", double.Parse(@e.Phone));
```

Expected result should be

```
(012) 345-6789
```

But the results I am getting is

```
(12) 345-6789
```

and the leading zero is missing, Hope someone can help me in this problem , Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `000` instead of `###`, read more about format in MSDN article [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String.Format("{0:(000) ###-####}", double.Parse(@e.Phone));
```

Format specifier "0"

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

Format specifier "#"

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

Comment: In this case, you can also just use the `double.Parse(@e.Phone).ToString("(000) 000-0000")`, instead of `String.Format(...)`